# how compile .c file when using vorbis library. undefined reference to vorbis_info_init

Tags: gcc, vorbis

I installed libvorbis-div with `sudo apt install libvorbis-dev`.
But when i tried to compile my simple code with `gcc a.c` command, i get "undefined reference to `vorbis_info_init'" error.

a.c

```
#include "vorbis/codec.h"
int main(int argc, char **argv){
   vorbis_info vi;
   vorbis_info_init(&vi);
   return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only running gcc a.c, then you are missing the linker arguments. You should introduce the library you are using to the compiler/linker, which in this case is gcc.

P.S. Probably just add -lvorbis, but don't just copy-paste, parse these flags in your brain!